# how to make "operator_menu_enum" keep the selected value displayed

Tags: scripting, python

I created a drop-down menu, with a `operator_menu_enum` referring to an `EnumProperty`.

When I select an entry in this menu, it closes, and display the default `text` string, instead of displaying the selected entry's string.

How to keep the selected entry displayed in the menu's head after selection ?

Edit : Here is an example script of the way I make the menu :

```
import bpy

class STUFF_PANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_stuffSelect"
    bl_label = "Stuff selection"
    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator_menu_enum("stuff_list.menu", 'stuffList', text="Stuff list")
        if bpy.props.selectedStuff:
            row = layout.row()
            row.label("Selected stuff :")
            row.label(str(bpy.props.selectedStuff[1]))


class STUFF_LIST_OT_Menu(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "stuff_list.menu"
    bl_description = "select something here"
    bl_label = "Menu"

    def get_stuff(self, context):
        return bpy.props.config_stuff_list

    stuffList = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        items = get_stuff, name = "Stuff", description = "The stuff list")

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.props.selectedStuff = [
            n for i, n in enumerate(bpy.props.config_stuff_list)\
            if n[0] == self.stuffList][0]
        return{'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.props.selectedStuff = False
    bpy.props.config_stuff_list = [
        ("1","stuff 1","0"),("2","stuff 2","0"),("3","stuff 3","0")]
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)


def unregister():
    del bpy.props.config_stuff_list
    del bpy.props.selectedStuff
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Could you pose a simple example script?

Comment: Ok, edited my question with an example of how I use the APi to make the menu.

Comment: `NameError: name 'bpy' is not defined`, please test the example and make sure it works.

Comment: Checked the example, looks like you may be better off not to use the API like this, can you explain what this is for?

Comment: This is part of a script which allows user to modify a configuration file, within the UI. (using python 'configparser' and so on). More precisely, this part correspond to a section of the config file which contains a list of json values, so the user have to choose a value to be able to modify the json content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature isn't supported by `operator_menu_enum`, the purpose of this is to be a submenu containing options. Not a persistent drop-down selection box, you may be better off to add an `update` callback to an enum property, then selecting an option can run some python code.

*What you wan't can be done, but I think you're looking in the wrong place.*

#### Simple answer:

You could replace the `row.operator_menu_enum` line with this.

```
    if bpy.props.selectedStuff:
        label = str(bpy.props.selectedStuff[1])
    else:
        label = "Stuff list"
    row.operator_menu_enum("stuff_list.menu", 'stuffList', text=label)
```

#### Longer answer:

it looks like this is not using the API correctly. You can't easily access operator properties from a panel (when the operator isn't running), you're better off to add a property-group to the scene that contains all your tool properties, then have the operators `invoke` function initialize from these settings (this is how most Blender operators do this).

#### Note:

- Setting attributes in `bpy.props` is bad practice, just store this in the script. (as a class attribute for example)

Comment: Your 'simple answer' works great at the moment, if I have enough time I'll go more in-depth with the other one. Thx!