# How can I get the id name of a submenu?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I'm looking at the ui_menu.py template script in Blender, and line 19 shows this line:

```
layout.operator_menu_enum("object.select_by_type",
                              property="type",
                              text="Select All by Type...",
                              )
```

[image] 
I thought I could find the id name "object.select_by_type" by hovering over Select -> Select All by Type... in the 3D viewport, but when I did, I couldn't see any grayish popup saying something like "Python: object.select_by_type()". How can find the id name of submenus like this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting, I've seen that a submenu can be made from one of two functions in a Menu subclass: **1. self.layout.operator_menu_enum()** or **2. self.layout.menu().**

## 1. self.layout.operator_menu_enum()

[image]
[image] 
If it's from operator_menu_enum(), you can hover your mouse over each option and the description will have the same function. For example, in Select -> Select All by Type..., each option you hover over has the description *Python: bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='[some option]')*. That's a good hint to say that the "Select All by Type..." menu was made from self.layout.operator_menu_enum().


(As a side note, I also see that the parameter name shown in the description is what you put in the property parameter when you're calling operator_menu_enum(). So since the parameter name in select_by_type() was "type", I'd call something in a custom script like `self.layout.operator_menu_enum(operator = "object.select_by_type", property = "type", text="select_menu test")`. And if I was making my own operator subclass for operator_menu_enum, apparently the variable name for the EnumProperty() you define is the string you put in the property parameter of operator_menu_enum(). I guessed that from this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/how-to-make-operator-menu-enum-keep-the-selected-value-displayed).)

## 2. self.layout.menu()

[image]
[image] 
If the menu is made from self.layout.menu(), you can hover over each option and you'll see different function names in the description. An example is View -> Align View. To find the id name string that you can use in self.layout.menu(), you can do a search in bpy.types. For example, here's the code and output I got from the Python Console when I was searching up bpy.types:

```
>>> for i in dir(bpy.types):
...     if "align" in i: print(i)
...     
ARMATURE_OT_align
IMAGE_MT_uvs_weldalign
OBJECT_OT_align
UV_OT_align
VIEW3D_MT_view_align
VIEW3D_MT_view_align_selected
```

I checked for "align" in the if statement because I thought it was the most logical thing, seeing that the submenu name was "Align View". And also by best guess, I saw that "VIEW3D_MT_view_align" was the id name for this submenu (I double checked in a custom script with something like `self.layout.menu(menu = "VIEW3D_MT_view_align", text = "align test")`). Anyways, that's the best I can come up with. I couldn't find anything in google this time.